# fsync() and write() in different threads

Tags: c++, c, linux, io

I am trying to write program using fsync() and write() but fsync need time to sync data but i haven't this time to wait. I made one more thread for fsync() 
Here is my code:

```
#include <thread>
void thread_func(int fd) {
    while (1) {
       if(fsync(fd) != 0)
           std::cout << "ERROR fsync()\n";
       usleep(100);
    }
}
int main () {
    int fd = open ("device", O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK);
    if (fd < 0) {
        std::cout << "ERROR: open()\n";
        return -1;
    }
    std::thread *thr = new std::thread (thread_func, fd);
    if (thr == nullptr) {
       std::cout << "Cannot create thread\n";
       close (fd);
       return -1;
    }
    while (1) {
       if (write (fd, 'x', 1) < 1)
          std::cout << "ERROR write()\n";
    }
    close(fd);
}
```

Question is:

is it need to lock different thread when i use file descriptor to fsync in other thread than main?
when i test my program without mutex it have no problem. and when i read man description for fsync it have nothing for different thread.

Answer (score 5):

If the fact that `fsync` takes time and even sometimes blocks for a very short time is a problem, then you are most probably doing something wrong.

Normally, you do not want to call `fsync` at all, ever. It is a serious anti-optimization to do so, and one will only ever want to do it if it must be assured that data has been written out<sup>1</sup>. In this case, however, you absolutely **want** `fsync` to block, this is not only works-as-intended, but necessary.
Only when `fsync` has returned, you know that it has done its task. You know that the OS has done its best to assure that data has been written, and only then it is safe to proceed. If you offload this to a background thread, you can just as well not call `fsync`, because you don't know when it's safe to assume data has been written.

If initiating writes is your primary goal, you use `sync_file_range` under Linux (which runs asynchronously) followed by a call to `fsync` some time later. The reason for following up with `fsync` is both to ensure that writes are done, and the fact that `sync_file_range` does not update metadata, so unless you are strictly overwriting already allocated data within the file, your writes may not be visible in case of a crash even though data is on disk (I can't imagine how that might happen since allocating more sectors to a file *necessarily* means metadata must be modified, but the manpage explicitly warns that this *can* happen).

---

<sup>1</sup>The `fsync` function still does not (and cannot) guarantee that data is on a permanent storage, it might still be somewhere in the cache hierarchy, such as a controller's or disk's write cache.

Comment: FWIW, I disagree that you shouldn't fsync; if anything fsync() before close() should be routine for apps that care about keeping data. Also, see the manual for `sync_file_range` which (now) warns "This system call is extremely dangerous and should not be used in portable programs." (Then goes on to explain).

Comment: @CraigRinger: fsync-before-close effectively disables lazy writeback, which is the default and is just good enough for 99.9% of all applications. Assuming the hardware doesn't suffer catastrophic failure, nor does power fail unexpectedly (UPS?), lazy writeback is 100% reliable. If catastrophic failure happens, however, you are out of luck anyway. If the hard drive explodes mid-sync, what am I going to do about it? As for `sync_file_range`, I agree, and my answer reflects that. However, the OP cannot afford to wait for `fsync`, and sadly this is the best thing you have available.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you require the thread for something else I would suggest you use the asynchronous I/O [aio](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/aio.7.html) library:

```
struct aiocb fsync_cb = {
      .aio_fildes = fd
    , .aio_sigevent = {
        .sigev_notify = SIGEV_NONE
    }
}

aio_fsync(O_SYNC, &fsync_cb);
```

There is also an equivalent variant for `write`.

```
struct aiocb write_cb = {
      .aio_fildes = fd
    , .aio_buf = buffer
    , .aio_nbytes = nbytes
    , .aio_offset = offset
    , .aio_sigevent = {
        .sigev_notify = SIGEV_NONE
    }
}

aio_write(&write_cb);
```

If you choose not to have any notificaton of success then you will have to check/wait at some point for completion:

```
while (aio_error(&write_cb) == EINPROGRESS);
```